# Best Toolkit for Ajax?

Tags: ajax

What is going to end up to be the toolkit of choice for Ajax development? I've been working with Ajax for several years now and it appears that every year a new toolkit gets attention and appears to become the one to go with. I started out with just using plain XHR, then GWT, then jQuery, now YUI. Everytime I go to a new shop they are using something else. Are we going to end up with lots of toolkits like we have now in five years?

Comment: This has nothing to do with AJAX.  Do we seem close to settling on a single programming language, operating system, CPU, etc.?

Comment: I realize it's a subjective question, but I'm attempting to define a trend and yes, it has everything to do with Ajax as the question is about "Ajax Toolkits". Should I go and learn 50 Ajax toolkits because those are available and could become a leader in the market? I'm trying to focus on the ones that appear to be a candidate for market share over the next few years. Generally, over time things tend to level out to a few leaders with lots of others in the sidelines. We aren't close to a single programming language, but in web development, there are leaders in certain market segments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's subjective and doesn't follow the StackOverflow faq guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have different needs, and prefer different approaches for javascript applications, so different toolkits makes sense.

I personally prefer to just write my own, as I find that I work around limitations in the toolkits, or they are much larger than what I need, so something minimal is helpful.

In unix there are many different shells to use, there are many editors for writing code, so why not have several toolkits.

Competition is good, otherwise the winner will get lazy and start to become obsolete.

I doubt we will standardize, programmers tend not to anyway, so why expect them to change.

Comment: Yes, but there was a list of 50 in 2006 and I have no idea how many are out there now. It think it's excessive at this point. For enterprise web development there is mostly java and .net, but that doesn't discount php, ruby, etc... however, they are the two leaders. Having several ajax toolkits is okay, but I don't want to learn all of the ones available, I just want to focus on the leaders.

Comment: @James - The best bet is to learn how to do what you need without a library, and then when you are told to use a given library, you just take advantage of it, but don't depend on it.  For example, I recently had to write a page that did in-place editing and sending the information back using onblur. I did that without a library as the amount of code was so small compared to the size of most libraries.

Comment: Point well taken. I hadn't thought of that. I was thinking from a commercial standpoint only, thinking that one toolkit would eventually emerge as the leader and that is what to focus on. Right now I think Flex still has a sizeable lead over anything else, but I don't know of anyone personally that works with it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm thinking GWT has an edge, because of several key factors: a java dev can get it working without extensive js knowledge, it follows the idea of java itself and makes it work (mostly) between browsers so the GWT code runs on multiple browsers without a lot of tweaks (some may disagree with me), it's supported by Google, and last of all, without a clear standard for all the browsers at this time, GWT may be the best way to do Ajax until browsers reach a higher level of standards. IMHO. Time will tell.